# Query to a nested sets table to exclude all marked substrees

Tags: mysql, sql, filter, group-by, nested-sets

I am creating a nested set with `left` and `right` columns. There is a column called `exclusion`. What I want to do is select all rows in the nested set but if the `exclusion` column is true, remove all other rows whose `left` and `right` column values fit between the exclusion rows `left` and `right` values.

Lets say my results look like this:

```
id | left | right | exclusion
-----------------------------
1  | 1    | 14    | 0
2  | 2    | 13    | 0
3  | 3    | 4     | 0
4  | 5    | 10    | 1
5  | 6    | 7     | 0
6  | 8    | 9     | 0
7  | 11   | 12    | 0
```

Running my query, I want the results to exclude rows 4, 5, and 6. 4 because the exclusion column is true. 5 and 6 because their left and right values fit between row 4's left and right values.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Exists` operator to existence of records. Try this.

```
SELECT *
FROM   Yourtable a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   Yourtable b
               WHERE  b.exclusion = 1
                      AND ( a.lefts NOT BETWEEN b.lefts AND b.rights
                            AND a.rights NOT BETWEEN b.lefts AND b.rights ))
```

Comment: This doesn't work in general. It just says there should exist node (b) for current node (a), where (b) is exclusion and it is not in the subtree of (a). For instance, set `exclusion=1` for #1, and your query still produces (1,2,3,7), where result set should be empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.*
FROM   ns c
JOIN   ns p ON p.left <= c.left AND p.right >= c.right
GROUP BY c.id
HAVING SUM(p.exclusion) = 0
```

It says that sum of `exclusion` in the path to root should be zero, thus meet no excluded parents. Here's [the SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/764a2/8), just in case.